# Remove part of the full directory name?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a list of filename with full path which I need to remove the filename and part of the file path considering a filter list I have.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(file)
```

Does part of the job but I was wondering if there is a simple way to filter the paths using .Net 2.0 to remove part of it.

For example:

if I have the `path + filename` equal to`C:\my documents\my folder\my other folder\filename.exe` and all I need is what is above `my folder\` means I need to extract only `my other folder` from it.

**UPDATE:**

The filter list is a text box with folder names separated by a `,` so I just have partial names on it like the above example the filter here would be `my folder`

**Current Solution based on Rob's code:**

```
string relativeFolder = null;
string file = @"C:\foo\bar\magic\bar.txt";
string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
string[] paths = folder.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string[] filterArray = iFilter.Text.Split(',');

foreach (string filter in filterArray)
{
    int startAfter = Array.IndexOf(paths, filter) + 1;
    if (startAfter > 0)
    {
        relativeFolder = string.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), paths, startAfter, paths.Length - startAfter);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The filter you mention is a precompiled array of directories or something?

Comment: It is a text box filled with folder names separated by `,` forgot to mention that thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
private static string GetRightPartOfPath(string path, string startAfterPart)
{
    // use the correct seperator for the environment
    var pathParts = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

    // this assumes a case sensitive check. If you don't want this, you may want to loop through the pathParts looking
    // for your "startAfterPath" with a StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase check instead
    int startAfter = Array.IndexOf(pathParts, startAfterPart);

    if (startAfter == -1)
    {
        // path not found
        return null;
    }

    // try and work out if last part was a directory - if not, drop the last part as we don't want the filename
    var lastPartWasDirectory = pathParts[pathParts.Length - 1].EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString());
    return string.Join(
        Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), 
        pathParts, startAfter,
        pathParts.Length - startAfter - (lastPartWasDirectory?0:1));
}
```

This method attempts to work out if the last part is a filename and drops it if it is.

Calling it with

```
GetRightPartOfPath(@"C:\my documents\my folder\my other folder\filename.exe", "my folder");
```

returns

> my folder\my other folder

Calling it with

```
GetRightPartOfPath(@"C:\my documents\my folder\my other folder\", "my folder");
```

returns the same.

Comment: thanks a lot for your code it helped me deal with my problem in a simple and clenner way i have updated my main post with the solution that is based on your code and is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this method to split the path by "\" sign (or "/" in Unix environments). After this you get an array of strings back and you can pick what you need.

```
        public static String[] SplitPath(string path)
        {
            String[] pathSeparators = new String[] 
            { 
                Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()
            };
            return path.Split(pathSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
```

Comment: that is sort of what I have, the folder splitted by \\ I am just not sure how to pick all the path from the folder filter name I need till the end where the filename starts.

Comment: careful with you choice of directory path seperators. "\" is true on Windows, but may not be on another platform.

Comment: @Prix: Rob's advice is still good advice. You can use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` instead of hard-coding one. Any time you *can* avoid magic strings you should.

Comment: Updated solution as suggested by @Prix and others